# FBFriendPickerViewController to fetch any users

Tags: ios, facebook, uiviewcontroller

Is there any way I can set the FBFriendPickerViewController to fetch users for given set of IDs where some of them are not necessary my friends (but for example friend of a friend). If not are there any open source controllers that perform such thing?